# GLFW joystick input issues

Tags: c++, glfw

I'm trying to get input from a joystick(Thrustmaster Hotas x, if it matters) with GLFW, but using glfwGetJoystickAxes and Buttons does not work as expected. The axes output as 00007FF77FC0D820 and there is no information about the state of the buttons. What would I be doing wrong here?

```
const float* Joystick::getAxesState()
{
    axes = glfwGetJoystickAxes(GLFW_JOYSTICK_1, &axesCount);
    return axes;
}

const unsigned char* Joystick::getButtonState()
{
    buttons = glfwGetJoystickButtons(GLFW_JOYSTICK_1, &buttonCount);
    return buttons;
}
```

Comment: glfwGetJoystickAxes and glfwGetJoystickButtons return float and unsigned char arrays respectively. Try accessing them as <axes_return>[index] and <buttons_return>[index]. They are of length <whatever_count_you_fed_it>

Comment: @NathanWride That fixed the problem, add it as an answer

Comment: Don't forget that you should call these functions only once. They return a pointer to GLFW's intrinsic state buffers, which are updated on their own by the event pump.

Comment: @Quentin I'll add that to my answer

Comment: If you're saving these pointers for longer than a frame, make sure you register a joystick callback. The the pointers will become invalid if the joystick / controller is disconnected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glfwGetJoystickAxes(<joystick>,<count>)` returns an array of `float[<count>]` `glfwGetJoystickButtons(<joystick>,<count>)` returns an array of `unsigned char[<count>]`

Try accessing them as `<axes_return>[index]` and `<buttons_return>[index]`.

Also as @Quentin mentioned, you should only call these functions once because the returns are pointers to glfw's internally stored states.